# I'm trying to use Telegraf Stage with TypeScript, but something is wrong with my typings

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, telegraf.js

Here's bot/index.ts:

```
import { Telegraf, Context, Scenes } from 'telegraf';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import LocalSession from 'telegraf-session-local';

const result = dotenv.config();
if (result.error || !result.parsed) {
  throw result.error || new Error('No data loaded from env');
}

export interface SessionData {
  lastRequest?: Date;
  menuMessage: number;
}

type BotContext = Context & Scenes.SceneContext;
type BotSession = SessionData & Scenes.SceneSession<Scenes.SceneSessionData>;
export interface Bot extends BotContext {
  session: BotSession;
}

const telegramKey: string = result.parsed['TELEGRAM_KEY'];
const bot = new Telegraf<Bot>(telegramKey);
const session = new LocalSession<Bot>({
  property: 'session'
});

bot.use(session.middleware());

export default bot;
```

And here's scenes/index.ts:

```
import { Scenes } from 'telegraf';
import scanImage from './scanImage.js';
import bot, { Bot, SessionData } from '../bot/index.js';

const stage = new Scenes.Stage<***Bot***>([scanImage]); // TS says that error here

export default stage;
```

Error:
`src/scenes/index.ts:5:33 - error TS2322: Type 'BaseScene<Bot>' is not assignable to type 'BaseScene<SessionContext<SceneSession<SceneSessionData>> & { scene: SceneContextScene<Bot, SceneSessionData>; }>'. Types of property 'enterHandler' are incompatible. Type 'MiddlewareFn<Bot>' is not assignable to type 'MiddlewareFn<SessionContext<SceneSession<SceneSessionData>> & { scene: SceneContextScene<Bot, SceneSessionData>; }>'. Type 'SessionContext<SceneSession<SceneSessionData>> & { scene: SceneContextScene<Bot, SceneSessionData>; }' is not assignable to type 'Bot'. Types of property 'session' are incompatible. Type 'SceneSession<SceneSessionData> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'BotSession'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'BotSession'. Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'SessionData'.`

What am i doing wrong?

I tried to google the problem, but nothing is working

Solutions from [here](https://github.com/telegraf/telegraf/issues/1139) did'nt help

Comment: The error goes away if you remove your `menuMessage`. I'm not familiar with telegraf, but this is the source of the problem

Comment: i cant remove it :(

Comment: It seems that you should :D

Comment: I tried just as experiment - it didn't work

Comment: Strange, worked for me locally. Type should be like this: `interface SessionData {lastRequest?: Date;}`

Comment: Really, it worked. But why?

Comment: The error message: `Property 'menuMessage' is missing in type 'SceneSession<SceneSessionData>' but required in type 'SessionData'`

Comment: So, how can i add my property to `'SceneSession<SceneSessionData>' `?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXrp9m) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer, otherwise what am I missing?